# Should I flag bad accepted answers if there are better ones?

Tags: discussion, flags, accepted-answer

Recently I found this question [sending json object from spring mvc controller to yui view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842693/sending-json-object-from-spring-mvc-controller-to-yui-view).

It contains answer with discussion that shows how to resolve OP problem, but there was also accepted "thank-you" type answer. If I flag this accepted answer it will be removed and question will lose its `hasaccepted` status so it won't be found in searching results if we use `hasaccepted:yes` flag.

On the one hand accepted answer is kind of useless here, but on the other removing hasaccepted status can do more charm then removing this answer.

What should I do in this kind of situations? Is there any third option? Can mods somehow "fix" it? Or maybe should I just edit that accepted answer and assume that last comment was the solution that OP was looking for?

Comment: Accepted or no, that's not an answer.

Comment: That's not even an answer at all.

Comment: Yes, and thats the problem. Is removing bad accepted answer more important than removing `hasaccepted` flag?

Comment: The'accepted'status isn't the issue, it's the fact that there is an answer there that isn't an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, no, you shouldn't flag an answer that is wrong just because it is accepted. The accepted status shouldn't play a role in whether an answer is flagged or not.

You should only flag for moderator attention when a moderator is needed to perform an action. In your current situation then you should flag the answer as 'not an answer'. That's what the primary problem is there, not the fact it's accepted.

It shouldn't matter that there is no longer an accepted answer on the question, there is still a *correct* answer. If people search SO looking for answers to their question but decide to limit their results to questions with accepted answers then they're doing themselves harm there as it's likely not all correct answers get officially accepted.

Comment: Thanks, last part of your answer was the one I was looking for.